# Dynamically populate dropdown list based on selected value of other dropdown list in JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want to dynamically populate dropdown list based on the value selected from another dropdown list (Which is also dynamically populated) in JSP.  When searching the internet I found a one solution which uses
onchange="this.form.submit(); in first dropdown list change event but it is not working well because I have other input boxes in the JSP form.

In other words: I have first dropdown list which is dynamically populated from category table. When I chose any category based on this category I want to populates all the data from sub-category table in the  second dropdown list

My JSP page is here

```
         <% List<Category> listCategory = CategoryDao.getAllCategory();
                                request.setAttribute("listCategory", listCategory);
                             %>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="inputCategoryCode">Product Category</label>
                   
                    <select name="fk_category_id" id="fk_category_id" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                     <option value="0">Select Product Category </option>
                    <c:forEach items="${listCategory}" var="category">
                    
                    <option value="${category.id}">${category.category_type}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="inputCity">Sub Category</label>
                    <select name="fk_subcategory_id" id="fk_subcategory_id" class="form-control">
                     <option value="0">Select Sub Category </option>
               <%
                    final Connection connection = db.getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement("select * from sub_category where prodcat_id = ?");
                    pstm.setString(1, request.getParameter("fk_category_id"));
                    ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
                
                  while(rs.next())
                  {
                      %>
                      <option value="<%=rs.getInt("id")%>"><%=rs.getString("sub_cat")%></option>
                      <%
                  }
                  

                %>
                     
                    
                </div>
```

---

Comment: Can you use ajax ?